# How to simulate default chrome history with chrome extension history/webNavigation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

So I want to simulate default history of chrome with chrome extension. I tried using mostly every event in [chrome.history](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) or [chrome.webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation), but it always returned ton of data for example every redirect from `https` to `https` or just `/` or some weird urls, but when you visit for example https://developer.chrome.com, in history you will have just `developer.chrome.com`, but in `chrome.history` you will have like 5 records.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(page) {
    console.log(page+' -webNavigation');
});
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(page) {
    console.log(page+' -history');
});
```

Can you help me please?

**EDIT**: These are the outputs:
Visited this site - developer.chrome.com
6 outputs from webNavigation:

```
https://developer.chrome.com/home -webNavigation
https://apis.google.com/u/0/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&siz..... -webNavigation
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=h..... -webNavigation
https://www.youtube.com/embed/1OSyfD1zOiY -webNavigation
about:blank -webNavigation
about:blank -webNavigation
```

2 outputs from history:

```
https://developer.chrome.com/ -history
https://developer.chrome.com/home -history
```

Another visited site www.youtube.com/.
1 output from webNavigation:

```
https://www.youtube.com/ -webNavigation
```

2 outputs from history

```
http://www.youtube.com/ -history
https://www.youtube.com/ -history
```

But in built-in history there is just one log

```
developer.chrome.com
```

and

```
www.youtube.com
```

Comment: Without seeing what you see currently, and what is the desired output, I doubt you'll get an answer because AFAIK there's no magic API to implement what you want exactly, and thus the task boils down to a set of conditions found empirically (e.g. via trial-and-error).

Comment: Okay, my bad. I'll post it.